# Matching Condition do not work with sse

Tags: scala, server-sent-events, gatling

I'm unable to perform check when using `jsonPath` (or any other matcher).

When using `message` I'm able to save whole JSON message in session

```
  .check(wsAwait
    .within(6 seconds)
    .until(1)
    .message.exists
    //.jsonpJsonPath("$.data").exists
    .saveAs("CID"))
```

And later in scenario I'm able to print whole message

```
{"event":"ConversationCreated",
  "data":"{"conversationId":"0e21f93d-6b0c-441f-a01d-8b0aa4e14769",
           "customerInfo":null,"deviceInfo":null}"}
```

---

But when using `pathJson` matcher, my check times out

```
  .check(wsAwait
    .within(6 seconds)
    .until(1)
    // .message.exists
    .jsonpJsonPath("$.data").exists
    .saveAs("CID"))
```

When run will produce

```
...
12:09:32.248 [ERROR] i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-2' crashed with 'java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: CID', forwarding to the next one
...

---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> Check failed: Timeout                                               1 (100,0%)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it "work".

The issue was lack of esceping JSON inside JSON.

Whene you send some data trough sse your clients receive both data and event type. And Gatling provides it as Json Object. If data you send is also Json Gatling will just pass it in as simple string, without any modification, which creates improper Json

Actuall:

```
{"event":"ConversationCreated",
  "data":"{"conversationId":"0e21f93d-6b0c-441f-a01d-8b0aa4e19",
           "customerInfo":null,"deviceInfo":null}"}
```

Proper:

```
{"event":"ConversationCreated",
  "data":"{\"conversationI\d":\"0e21f93d-6b0c-441f-a01d-8b0aa4e19\",
           \"customerInfo\":null,\"deviceInfo\":null}\"}
```

Or, rather than keeping `message` in Json, it could be kept as object:

```
case class Message(event: String, data: String)
```